# Convert Variable Header to JSON JArray

Tags: c#, json, json.net, json-deserialization

I have code that gets data from JSON:

```
dynamic myJSON = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(sourceString);
foreach (var item in myJSON["data"]["results"])
{ ... }
```

Now, I'd like to make this part `myJSON["data"]["results"]` for versatile, ideally by passing in a variable such as:

```
dynamic myJSON = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(sourceString);
var variableResults = ((Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JArray) string.Format("myJSON[\"{0}\"][\"{1}\"]", myData, myResults);
foreach (var item in variableResults)
{ ... }
```

I've tried different conversions, and looked here, but no question comes close, and the conversions always comes out string, not a JArray. Any ideas?

Comment: um .. `foreach (var item in myJSON[myData][myResults])` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`JObject`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JObject.htm) to parse it:

```
var json = "{asd: {qwe: [1,2,3,4]}}";
var obj = JObject.Parse(json);

// just plug in your variables here
var myData = "asd";
var myResult = "qwe";
var path = $"{myData}.{myResult}";
foreach (var item in obj.SelectToken(path).ToObject<int[]>())
{
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Could be better to use `obj.SelectToken("asd.qwe")` instead of obj["asd"]["qwe"] ? At least you can compose the path to the node.

Comment: It definitely seems like a better idea.

Comment: What a great idea! It's simple, has easily configurable values, and even doesn't throw an error, it just returns an easily testable null value.

Answer (score 1):

My solution ended up being:

```
// User would use a textbox with space separated values like "data results"
var parameterList = textBox1.Text.Trim().Replace(" ", ".");

var jsonObject = JObject.Parse(sourceString);
var jsonList = jsonObject.SelectToken(parameterList);
if (jsonList == null) { ... }

foreach (var item in jsonList)
{ ... }
```